# What's the comma for in this code example?

Tags: ruby, syntax

```
cash = 100_000.00
sum = 0
cash += 1.00, sum while cash < 1_000_000.00 # underscores ignored
```

I found the above example in a book "Learning Ruby" but using Ruby 1.9 it doesn't compile ("interpret"?)

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting $end
```

What's the comma supposed to be doing after 1.00?

Here's the full context of the example:

```
#Also, like if, you can use while as a statement modifier, at the end of a statement:
cash = 100_000.00
sum = 0
cash += 1.00, sum while cash < 1_000_000.00 # underscores ignored
#So cash just keeps adding up until it equals $1,000,000.00. I like that!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an error.  There's an [unconfirmed error report](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529864/errata/9780596529864.unconfirmed) about it, but nothing in the [official errata](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529864/errata/9780596529864.confirmed) (which haven't been updated since October 16, 2007).

Answer (score 2):

it's most likely meant to be a semicolon, but the code would still be wrong. I feel like there is some context missing. What is the author doing with sum?

you can use while in the following way which may help explain the intent.

```
i = 0
puts i +=1 while i < 10
```

Which means that this code would make sense

```
cash += 1.00 while cash < 1_000_000.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it wouldn't be the first nor the last programming book to have a glaring typo in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a mistyped or misprinted semi-colon(;)?

Answer (score 0):

The full context is as follows:

> Also, like if, you can use while as a statement modifier, at the end of
>   a statement:
>
> ```
> cash = 100_000.00
> sum = 0
>
> cash += 1.00, sum while cash < 1_000_000.00 # underscores ignored
> ```
>
> So cash just keeps adding up until it equals $1,000,000.00. I like that!

There is obviously at least one mistake here.  My guess is that the author accidentally used a perl or C style comma operator, then removed only part of the offending statement.